# My config file on ssh seems to systematicaly apply the * rule i don't know why ?

Tags: git, ssh, rsa, ssh-config

My config file on ssh seems to systematicaly apply the * rule i don't know why ?

```
 Host gitlab_perso
  HostName gitlab.com
  User git
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/perso/id_rsa

Host gitlab.com
 Hostname gitlab.com
 AddKeysToAgent yes


    UseKeychain yes
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

   Host *
     AddKeysToAgent yes
     UseKeychain yes
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

so only my default ssh key  ( ~/.ssh/id_rsa ) is always use . 
How the ssh config works ? 
thank your for your help !

Comment: Is your file really indented like that? It's hard to read.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for [programming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/about).

Comment: Based on your indentation, do you expect the `Host *` section to only apply when connecting to `gitlab.com`?

Answer (score 0):

To use non-default key either use it explicitly:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/perso/id_rsa git@gitlab.com
```

or use the host alias from your ssh config:

```
ssh gitlab_perso
```

If you need to use the key in git you have to change the host in remote's URL:

```
git remote set-url origin git@gitlab_perso:user/repo.git
```